# How to add custom pages in the moodle

Tags: moodle

in moodle 3.3+ i did not find any options for add static pages in admin panel.So where did i find that options or is there new functionality for adding static pages.
Please provide me some appropriate references.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Without coding:**

Moodle does not have a custom page option. The closest you will get without coding is the Page activity module, but that is at the course level. You may be interested in the static pages plugin: https://moodle.org/plugins/local_staticpage

**With coding:**

Check out their documentation on creating new pages: https://docs.moodle.org/dev/Page_API